# Button won't trigger IBAction outlet selector after popping back to view controller

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton

I have a very strange issue that just came up recently in my code (it used to work fine until, I think it was iOS 10).

I have a tab bar and one of the tabs is a view controller with a view finder so I can scan a bar code. On this screen, I have a button to turn the torch (flashlight) on, in case it's a bit dark and you can't see the barcode very well.

Once a barcode is scanned, I push to a controller that loads some things, and then when that finishes, it pushes to another controller to display the results.

From the results controller, if you hit the back button, I have it set to pop to the root view controller (i.e. the view finder).

What's weird is suddenly (as of iOS 10 or Xcode 8 I think) the torch button no longer works after you've scanned an object and return to the view finder...it's visible and enabled, but it won't trigger the IBAction method anymore. I don't disable the button anywhere in my code, and I even set a breakpoint on viewDidAppear to verify that the button *is* enabled, it's the same object (i.e. the button didn't get deleted and a new one created or something weird), and its target is still the correct view controller I would expect (I was wondering if somehow it lost a reference to its outlet selector, but that doesn't appear to be happening).

Also, I used the "Debug View Hierarchy" to verify that there is no invisible view sitting on top of the button and preventing it from being tapped (not that I expected there to be one, but I just wanted to make sure).

If I haven't scanned anything yet, I can turn the torch on/off fine (the torch button triggers the selector without an issue), and if I select another tab on the tab bar and then select the tab with the view finder again, the torch button still works fine (BTW, I have code in viewWillDisappear to turn the torch off just to make sure it's not on when you leave the view finder).

I don't think I've ever seen this issue before where the button is enabled but just stops triggering the IBAction. Any ideas?

### Summary:

Button works 100% correctly, until you push other view controllers on the stack and then pop back to root: then suddenly, even though it's visible, it's enabled, it has the correct target, and no invisible view is overlaying/blocking it, the button won't trigger the IBAction outlet selector. And this issue started happening recently (I think it was when I went up to Xcode 8 / iOS 10).

Comment: Is it happening for all other ios versions now (8 and 9)?

Comment: As far as I remember, it didn't happen on iOS 9, and I'm positive it didn't happen on iOS 8. Unfortunately, I don't have an iOS 8 or 9 device in front of me to run on right now, since I upgraded my phone to 10.

Comment: Did you try cleaning your project and reconnecting the outlet? or just try re-installing Xcode (It may sound stupid but i had an issue with UIKit that got fixed on its own, on re-installing xcode)

Comment: I just installed Xcode 8.2 (I installed it separate, I didn't upgrade to it), and this was happening even with Xcode 8.0...so I don't think reinstalling Xcode will fix it in this case. Also, I just tried uninstalling the app, removing the outlet, cleaning out the build folder completely, clearing out derived data, reconnecting the outlet, and reinstalling the app...and it didn't fix the issue either.

Comment: Possibly a silly question, but did you do `super.viewDidLoad()` in your `viewDidLoad()` function? You could also try `self.reloadInputViews()`...

Comment: Could you share your code with us? I mean VC with overriden methods (among the others, earlier mentioned viewWillDisappear)?

Comment: I've explained everything and I don't think the code will be very helpful in this case (there are too many pieces to put in an SO post and I can't really show the relevant things like the IBAction outlet to the storyboard). I'm not doing anything unusual in the code...I was just wondering if someone knew of some new iOS 10 issue or something.